# Prevent duplicate objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, singleton

This isn't exactly a singleton, but it's close, so I imagine it's common. I have a class (Foo) in which instances correspond to external data structures with unique IDs. I want to ensure that no two instances of Foo can have the same ID - if a constructor is called with the same id value, the *original* Foo instance with that ID, and all the other values are simply updated. In other words, something like:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(id, var1, var2)
    if Foo.already_has? id
      t = Foo.get_object(id)
      t.var1 = var1
      t.var2 = var2
      return t
    else
      @var1 = var1
      @var2 = var2
    end
end
```

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. I could keep an array of all instances of Foo as a class-level variable, then calling foo_instances.push(self) at the end of the initialization method. This strikes me as kind of ugly.
2. I believe Ruby already keeps track of instances of each class in some array - if so, is this accessible, and would it be any better than #1?
3. ??? (Ruby seems to support some slick [meta-]programming tricks, so I wouldn't be surprised if there already is a tidy way of doing this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `Foo.new` in your object, and do whatever you want in there:

```rb
class Foo
  def self.new(id, var1, var2)
    return instance if instance = self.lookup
    instance = self.allocate
    instance.send :initialize, var1, var2
    return self.store(instance)
  end
end
```

You can also, obviously, use a different class method to obtain the object; make the `initialize` method private to help discourage accidental allocation.

That way you only have one instance with every ID, which is generally much less painful than the pattern you propose.

You still need to implement the `store` and `lookup` bits, and there isn't anything better than a `Hash` or `Array` in your class to do that with.

You want to think about wrapping the things you store in your class in a [WeakRef](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html) instance, but still returning the real object.  That way the class can enforce uniqueness without also constraining that every single ID ever used remain in memory all the time.

That isn't appropriate to every version of your circumstances, but certainly to some.  An example:

```rb
  # previous code omitted ...
  return store(instance)
end

def self.store(instance)
  @instances ||= {}
  @instances[instance.id] = WeakRef.new(instance)
  instance
end

def self.lookup(id)
  @instances ||= {}
  if weakref = @instances[id] and weakref.weakref_alive?
    return weakref.__getobj__  # the wrapped instance
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to allocate - I didn't realize that existed. As for the lookup, though, is there a better way to do that than to create/manage the array of instances manually?

Comment: Nope.  Well, maybe a `Hash`, but that isn't really different.

Comment: Actually, wait - you almost certainly want to wrap a `WeakRef`, from the standard library, around your objects in that array - so they don't linger forever: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html

Comment: What if an object is deleted, and garbage collection does not occur before the constructor is called again? Do I need to call Objectspace.garbage_collect at the beginning of each call to .new?

Comment: I updated the answer, but in short: no, don't do anything about garbage collection.  Hold a weakref internally, but return the real object to the caller, so they keep it alive.